# При клике на кнопку, первый раз уведомление появляется не плавно

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Кто-нибудь подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при клике на кнопку с первого раза уведомление появляется не плавно, а уже со второго раза плавно.

Вот пример - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/fgbsxbb8/8/)

А вот код:

```
<a class="add-to-cart addtocard-product" href="#">Щёлкни</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) {
  var tekst = $('<div id="message-success"><p>Привет! Меня показывают и скрывают:)</p></div>'),
      linc = $('#jGrowl');
  linc.html(tekst).fadeIn(); 
  setTimeout(function() {linc.fadeOut();}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо!:)

Ошибка была в том, что у меня не хватало `display: none;` для `div` с `id="jGrowl"`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-cart', function (e) {
  var tekst = $('<div id="message-success"><p>Привет! Меня показывают и скрывают:)</p></div>'),
      linc = $('#jGrowl');
  linc.html(tekst).fadeIn(); 
  setTimeout(function() {linc.fadeOut();}, 2000);
});
```

```css
#message-success{
    position: fixed;
      padding: 10px; 
      margin: 0px; 
      width: 299px; 
      top: 20px; 
      text-align: center; 
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
      right: 20px;  
    background-color:#79ad68;
}
#jGrowl{
    margin: 0 12px 0 12px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
.addtocard-product{padding: 10px 0 10px 0;background: #1DB6BD;display: block;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;color: #fff;width: 200px;text-align: center;transition:0.4s 0.2s ease;-moz-transition:0.4s 0.2s ease;-o-transition:0.4s 0.2s ease;-webkit-transition:0.4s 0.2s ease;}
.addtocard-product:hover{background: #03dae3;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="add-to-cart addtocard-product" href="#">Щёлкни</a>
<div id="jGrowl"></div>
```